# problems with itextPdf, Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.itextpdf.awt.PdfGraphics2D>

Tags: java, android, mobile, itext

I am quiet new to android and i am trying to convert a Bitmap to Pdf in android. I am using itextpdf 5.5.4 jar file. The code that i am using is written below:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.BadElementException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public void savePhotoPDF()
    {
        String currentTimestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"CameraApp");
        File picPDF = new File(dir.getPath()+File.separator+"IMG_"+currentTimestamp+".pdf");

        //File picPDF = new File(dir.getPath(),"abcd.pdf");

        Document document = new Document();
        try
        {


            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(picPDF));
            document.open();

            addImage(document);
            document.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //private static void addImage(Document document)
    private void addImage(Document document)
    {
        try
        {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            clickedPhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

            bArray = stream.toByteArray();

            image = Image.getInstance(bArray);  ///Here i set byte array..you can do bitmap to byte array and set in image...
        }
        catch (BadElementException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        // image.scaleAbsolute(150f, 150f);
        try
        {
            document.add(image);
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

in the above code, clickedPhoto is nothing but a Bitmap type defined as:

```
clickedPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);
```

I have compiled the itextpdf library as well in app gradle:

```
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.6'
```

But i don't know why, but the image(Bitmap:clickedPhoto) as pdf is not getting saved at the given location and in android monitor i can see:

```
10-11 18:54:53.154 24531-24531/com.example.abhisheksirohi.myapplication I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.itextpdf.awt.PdfGraphics2D>
10-11 18:54:53.158 24531-24531/com.example.abhisheksirohi.myapplication I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.itextpdf.awt.PdfPrinterGraphics2D>
```

I would be really glad if somebody could help me to resolve this exception. Thank you!!

Comment: there may be the issue with jar file. decode the jar which you are using and check this class exist or not. If not use the latest jar or old jar for finding this class. latest jar is 5.5.10 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.10

Comment: I checked it already and it has this class. This is why i am unable to understand why it is encountering this problem.

Comment: wait i'm also decoding this jar

Comment: Hey please use latest jar. I decoded latest jar and class is present in this package. "com.itextpdf.text.Document". First download latest jar and use  5.5.10 instead of 5.5.4. Let me know if still it does not work.

Comment: are you coding in eclipse?

Comment: No i am coding in android studio...@da

Comment: @DäñishShärmà instead of compiling jar, i used compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.6'...so now atlas it is not showing exception

Comment: but next problem that i have is

Comment: I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.itextpdf.awt.PdfGraphics2D>

Comment: download jar from here:https://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/

Comment: There's a specific jar for Android and it doesn't include anything from awt as Android doesn't support it.

Comment: @PauloSoares could you please give me the URL from where i can download that jar or let me know the way to compile that particular library in my grade file.??

Comment: Info here: http://developers.itextpdf.com/itextg-android

Comment: 1. Do NOT download from Sourceforge! Sourceforge is obsolete. Only download from itextpdf.com or github.com/itext. 2. If you are developing on Android, then you need the Android port called `itextg`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are developing on Android. This means you need the Android port of iText, which is called **iTextG**. iTextG is identical to iText (same code base), except for anything that uses AWT and some other stuff that isn't available on Android.

You can find iTextG on the iText website: http://developers.itextpdf.com/itextg-android

You can either use Gradle, or download the jar from the release page on Github: https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/releases/latest (use the itextg zip). As of October 2016, the latest version is 5.5.10.

**Please do not download from SourceForge!** SourceForge is obsolete, iText Software doesn't use it any more. This is because SourceForge is no longer trustworthy. [There have been incidents where SourceForge injected spyware into the installers of other software.](http://www.howtogeek.com/218764/warning-don%E2%80%99t-download-software-from-sourceforge-if-you-can-help-it/) While this has not yet happened to iText (and is unlikely to happen because of the nature of our software), we cannot condone these actions and we tell all our users and customers to avoid SourceForge.

Comment: the link you provided is not up furthermore. http://developers.itextpdf.com/itextg-android

I am facing same issue using gradle      compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.6'

Comment: Use `com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10` instead.

Comment: Thanks for reporting the broken link, it has been resolved.

Comment: Thx, had the same problem and now it works fine with iTextG.